# How can I receive the output from a remote (ssh) tail -F command on my local machine with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, automated-tests, remote-access

I am looking for a good way to have a python script that establishes an ssh connection, does a tail -F command on a log file, and receives each line as it is appended to the file in real time so I can further process it and check for certain things. I have tried using tail -1 in an infinite loop, but often times many lines are added almost instantaneously so this is not practical. This is for an automation framework which currently uses Exscript for executing commands over ssh, but I haven't found anything in the docs about this, so I am open to other libraries as well.

I have looked far and wide for many hours for a solution, and nothing is up to date or exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: check Paramiko library

Comment: `ssh ... | python your_script.py` and read from stdin.